# How can i limit the size of my availability calender by adjusting my existing CSS?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I'm using drupal (jollyness) theme and I am hosting a mock up site at seosolutions.london

I have been trying to see if there is a css work around to either "prevent my calendar displaying more than one month at a time" OR "to hide any extra months from view"

I have tried playing around with the widths of the various container divs (using chrome developer) but nothing seems to make a difference.

does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
.cal-viewport { width: 220px !important; }
```

Although you should refrain from using `!important` in your CSS, it is needed in this case (as inline styles are being applied).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer,although an issue here would be that if I were to click 'next month' I would then be shown a blank calendar.  I would want to block every month except the current month.

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS file instead: `.cal-viewport { width: 220px !important; }` (and remove the other styles I suggested)

Comment: Im not sure if I should be starting a seperate post for this but - Could I be really cheeky and ask... when a user clicks on a date in my calendar, how would i keep that specific date highlighted or bordered? (I would only want one date at a time to be selected)

Comment: That seems more like a JavaScript topic, so I would put that in a separate question. Also, I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you. Thanks.